# AWS permission to list subset of IAM roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I have an IAM role `my-role` that I want to allow the `aws iam list-roles` call. However, I don't want to return simply all roles, but only some that are relevant to `my-role`, for example, those which are tagged by some specific tag `foo=bar` (or filter on name is also acceptable for me).

When I configure `my-role` permission like this:

```
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListRoles"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/foo": "bar"
                }
            }
        }
```

I get an error when I call `aws iam list-roles`:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListRoles operation: User: arn:aws:sts::849104738271:assumed-role/my-role/i-0b9242f9846123b29 is not authorized to perform: iam:ListRoles on resource: arn:aws:iam::849104738271:role/ because no identity-based policy allows the iam:ListRoles action
```

I've also tried to remove the `Condition` part and change the prefix of `Resource` and using the `--path-prefix` parameter to `list-roles`, but the roles that I want to return have path `/` and the prefix is only a part of `RoleName`.

How can I adjust the privileges, or change the request so that I get the roles with specified tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Actions, resources, and condition keys for AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awsidentityandaccessmanagementiam.html) for `ListRoles` does *NOT* list any fields as valid `Conditions`.

Therefore, you can only grant permission to list *ALL* roles, or *NOT* to list roles. There is **no ability to limit what roles are requested or returned**.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but thank you for your answer!